# Most efficient way to glTexture from NSImage?

Tags: image, cocoa, opengl, nsimage, nsimagerep

(**UPDATE BELOW...**)

OpenGL Cocoa/OSX Desktop ap targeting 10.8+

I have a situation where I am receiving an NSImage object once per frame and would like to convert it to an openGL texture (it is a video frame from an IPCamera). From SO and the internet, the most helpful utility method I could find for converting NSImage to glTexture is the code below.

While this is fine for occasional (IE Loading) situations, it is a massive performance hog and terrible to run once per frame. I have profiled the code and narrowed the bottleneck to two calls. Together these calls account for nearly two thirds of the running time of my entire application.

1. The bitmaprep creation

   ```
    NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[inputImage TIFFRepresentation]];
   ```

   Thinking that the problem was perhaps in the way I was getting the bitmap, and because I've heard bad things performance wise about TIFFRepresentation, I tried this instead, which is indeed faster, but only a little and also introduced some odd color-shifting (everything looks red):

   ```
   NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, inputImage.size.width, inputImage.size.height);
   CGImageRef cgImage = [inputImage CGImageForProposedRect:&rect context:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] hints:nil];
   NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
   ```
2. The glTexImage2D call (I have no idea how to improve this.)

How can I make the method below more efficient?

Alternatively, tell me I'm doing it wrong and I should look elsewhere? The frames are coming in as MJPEG, so I could potentially use the NSData before it's converted to NSImage. However, it's jpeg encoded so I'd have to deal with that. I also actually want the NSImage object for another part of the application.

```
-(void)loadNSImage:(NSImage*)inputImage intoTexture:(GLuint)glTexture{


    // If we are passed an empty image, just quit
    if (inputImage == nil){
        //NSLog(@"LOADTEXTUREFROMNSIMAGE: Error: you called me with an empty image!");
        return;
    }


    // We need to save and restore the pixel state
    [self GLpushPixelState];
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTexture);


    //  Aquire and flip the data
    NSSize imageSize = inputImage.size;
    if (![inputImage isFlipped]) {
        NSImage *drawImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:imageSize];
        NSAffineTransform *transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];

        [drawImage lockFocus];

        [transform translateXBy:0 yBy:imageSize.height];
        [transform scaleXBy:1 yBy:-1];
        [transform concat];

        [inputImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint
                                fromRect:(NSRect){NSZeroPoint, imageSize}
                               operation:NSCompositeCopy
                                fraction:1];

        [drawImage unlockFocus];

        inputImage = drawImage;
    }

    NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[inputImage TIFFRepresentation]];


    //  Now make a texture out of the bitmap data
    // Set proper unpacking row length for bitmap.
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, (GLint)[bitmap pixelsWide]);

    // Set byte aligned unpacking (needed for 3 byte per pixel bitmaps).
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    NSInteger samplesPerPixel = [bitmap samplesPerPixel];

    // Nonplanar, RGB 24 bit bitmap, or RGBA 32 bit bitmap.
    if(![bitmap isPlanar] && (samplesPerPixel == 3 || samplesPerPixel == 4)) {

        // Create one OpenGL texture
        // FIXME: Very slow
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
                     GL_RGBA,//samplesPerPixel == 4 ? GL_RGBA8 : GL_RGB8,
                     (GLint)[bitmap pixelsWide],
                     (GLint)[bitmap pixelsHigh],
                     0,
                     GL_RGBA,//samplesPerPixel == 4 ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB,
                     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                     [bitmap bitmapData]);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    }else{
        [[NSException exceptionWithName:@"ImageFormat" reason:@"Unsupported image format" userInfo:nil] raise];
    }
    [self GLpopPixelState];
}
```

### **Screenshot of the profile:**

[image]

## **Update**

Based on Brad's comments below, I decided to look at simply bypassing NSImage. In my particular case I was able to get access to the JPG data as an NSData object prior to it being converted into an NSImage and so this worked great:

```
  [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData: imgData];
```

Using more or less the same method above but starting directly with the bitmap rep, CPU usage fell from 80% to 20% and I'm satisfied with the speed. I have a solution for my ap.

I would still like to know if there is an answer to my original question or if it's best to just accept this as an object lesson in what to avoid. Finally I'm still wondering if it's possible to improve the load time on the glTexImage2D call - although it's now well within the realm of reasonable, it still profiles as taking up 99% of the load of the method (but maybe that's ok.)

===========

Comment: Have you profiled this? Are you sure that the `glTexImage2D()` is really the slowest part of the above? Placing this in NSImage and redrawing via Core Graphics would seem to be much slower than the actual texture upload.

Comment: Just posted a screenshot of the time profile. It's possible I'm reading that wrong, but it looks to me like the two bottlenecks are allocating the NSBitmapImageRep and glTexImage2D

Comment: Also appears that the texture upload is the worst offender... which I agree is surprising.

Comment: I still think that you're going to want to find a way to avoid passing through NSImage, probably by using another JPEG decoding implementation that gets you raw bytes. I don't have enough put together for a full answer, but check out Apple's guidelines for texture uploads: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/opengl-macprogguide/opengl_texturedata/opengl_texturedata.html , in particular the GL_TEXTURE_STORAGE_HINT_APPLE parameter and the glTextureRangeAPPLE() function. I've used those in the past to dramatically speed up texture uploads.

Comment: Yeah... Thank you for your time and for the specific pointers to the apple functions I hadn't seen. I think I'm coming around to the same somewhat frustrating conclusion (that I just need to acquire the textures a different way). I'm going to leave the question open a bit longer in case there are any other ideas. If not, then I'll ask you to post that as an answer anyway and will accept? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your data is coming in, you could use a Pixel Buffer Object (PBO), which will use DMA when uploading the texture (avoiding the CPU), whereas a random pointer will be copied using memcpy (using the CPU).

Apple describe how to do this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/opengl-macprogguide/opengl_texturedata/opengl_texturedata.html

Basically a PBO gives you a chunk of memory that OpenGL can DMA, so use it to allocate the momory into which you copy your decompressed frames, then draw by binding the buffer and calling glTexSubImage2D with nil as the memory reference.

This does rely on you being able to take your incoming data straight into the PBO - otherwise you’ll still need to memcpy to the PBO, losing any benefit it could bring.

Comment: Thanks for this, especially for the explanation of why the PBO is faster. I'm going to accept this answer with the following note for myself or other folks finding this: The answer to my question (most efficient way from NSImage->glTexture) is: Don't do it :D The code above is about as good as it gets, if you need the data at a reasonable frame rate, find another way to access the pixels - going via NSImage is just too slow.